# Renombrar archivo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando realizar una automatización de descargas de archivos, el problema es que quiero renombrar el archivo que se descarga, por ejemplo, el archivo que descargo es el siguiente:

archivo.csv

Este archivo lo quiero renombrar a archivo_1.csv, si vuelvo a descargar el archivo lo quiero renombrar a archivo_2.csv y así sucesivamente, he logrado hacer esto:

```
function hora() {
  var hour = new Date().getHours(); 
  var uno = 1; 
  var dos = 2; 
  if (hour < 15) {
    return uno;
  } else {
    return dos;
  }
}
```

De esta forma concateno el nombre mas el resultado de la variable.
Claramente mi función solo funciona 2 veces...

Comment: solo funciona dos veces porque hour será como mucho 23, y como poco 0. No entiendo bien qué pinta la hora, o lo que pretendes pero así a bote pronto, tienes que guardar en algún sitio el número de veces que descargas el archivo

Comment: Puedes comprobar si ya existe el fichero `\`archivo${n}.csv\`` e ir aumentando n hasta que no exista

Comment: Guarda un Contador en localStorage o en una variable global, localStorage.setItem("miContador", contador+1);  para obtenerlo var contador=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("miContador"));

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco lo que intente hacer con la hora fue lo siguiente: si lo ejecuto antes de las 15 horas devuelvo un 1, eso lo concateno con el nombre y queda en archivo_1.csv, si ejecuto el script después de las 15 horas devuelvo un 2, debo aclarar que de Javascript no se mucho y es lo que se me ocurrió...

Comment: Consulta, necesitas contar con un histórico de archivos y guardarlos con nombre de fecha y hora?, o lo que necesitas es crear el nuevo archivo renombrando y sobreescribiendo el existente. Ejm.: archivo.csv (nuevo), archivo1.csv?